# pgbouncer kill command blocks subsequent connections

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, pgbouncer

According to https://pgbouncer.github.io/usage.html running `KILL db;` should *immediately drop all client and server connections on given database.*
I was trying to stop all the connections to postgres on my test environment using

```
=# kill postgres;
```

and it really closed all client and server connections, but i couldn't connect to postgres anymore.

```
$ psql -h localhost -p 6543 postgres
psql: ERROR: pgbouncer cannot connect to server
```

In postgresql.log i have the following message

```
[2016-04-27 16:21:38 u=postgres d=postgres h=[local] p=12458 l=1] LOG: could not send data to client: Broken pipe
[2016-04-27 16:21:38 u=postgres d=postgres h=[local] p=12458 l=2] FATAL: connection to client lost
```

pgBouncer realod doesn't change the situation, only restart helps.

```
=# show databases;
name     │ host │ port │ database │ force_user │ pool_size │ reserve_pool │ pool_mode │ max_connections │ current_connections
─────────┼──────┼──────┼──────────┼────────────┼───────────┼──────────────┼───────────┼─────────────────┼─────────────────────

postgres │ NULL │ 5454 │ postgres │ NULL       │         5 │ 100          │ NULL      │ 0               │ 0


=# show version;
NOTICE: pgbouncer version 1.7.2
```

1. Can anyone explain what happened?
2. Is there a way to repair postgres-connection through pgbouncer without restart?
3. if database connection locking is expected behavior of kill command, how can i close all connections without blocking new ones?

Thanks, Mikhail

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Resume** command to pgBouncer.

This isn't documented accurately in pgBouncer's section about [Process Controlling Commands](https://pgbouncer.github.io/usage.html#process-controlling-commands), but a `KILL db;` command actually needs a subsequent `RESUME db;` command to allow connections.

If you look at your pgBouncer log file, you should see entries like this:

`2016-12-16 22:07:10.224 5720 LOG C-0x851e28: dbname/username@127.0.0.1:42421 login attempt: db=dbname user=username tls=no
2016-12-16 22:07:10.224 5720 LOG C-0x851e28: dbname/username@127.0.0.1:42421 closing because: pgbouncer cannot connect to server (age=0)
2016-12-16 22:07:10.224 5720 WARNING C-0x851e28: dbname/username@127.0.0.1:42421 Pooler Error: pgbouncer cannot connect to server
2016-12-16 22:07:10.224 5720 LOG S-0x85aae0: dbname/username@(bad-af):0 closing because: pause mode (age=0)`

Note that pgBouncer claims it is in **pause mode** in this log, and I see the same errors reported by psql while it is in this state:

`psql: ERROR:  pgbouncer cannot connect to server`

After a `RESUME db;` command to pgBouncer, connections should work again.